# Firebase how can i reproduce this Exception (The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.) in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can I reproduce this exception in Firebase Authentication in android app?

```
com.google.firebase.auth.h: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblv.zzce(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbls$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd.zze(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbly$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: create and login the account with email/password and then tried to log in with google after that log in with email/password.

Comment: You can reproduce as you told i.e. **create and login the account with email/password and then tried to log in with google after that log in with email/password.** OR do you mean anything else by *reproduce*?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, tried it but it does not reproduce since that login with email/password on the second try was successful

Answer (score 0):

The user does not have a password anymore. That is why you are getting that error. When you login with Google after an email/password creation, it will remove the password. This is a security mechanism as the account was unverified when email/pass was created. I can go create an email/pass with your gmail. You go and sign in with gmail to app. I should not keep my access to your account.

Answer (score 0):

Your password was probably too simple. Google let's you signin with a simple password from localhost but once you host the app and attempt to signin it will block you. Simply reset your password. Don't use "password" or "123456" anymore. LOL.